# Issue with dependency upgrade of maven-compat from switching 3.0-alpha-2 to 3.3.9

Tags: maven, dependencies, conflict

I am using object of `ArtifactResolver` in my `JUnit` test class in following way

```
final ArtifactResolver resolver = (ArtifactResolver)this
                    .getContainer().lookup(ArtifactResolver.ROLE);
```

It works fine when I am using `maven-compat` dependency with version `3.0-alpha-2`.
But, I had to update this dependency `version to 3.3.9` to use certain upgraded methods and code.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

The moment, I upgrade its version, I started getting following error in my eclipse and Jenkins central both

```
Error injecting: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
  1)  No implementation for org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystem was bound.
      while locating org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver
      at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.MergedModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
      at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.MergedModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
      while locating org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolver

 1 error
          role: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolver
      roleHint: 
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:243)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:237)
        at com.cwsoft.plugins.build.artifact.DownloadMojoTest.init(DownloadMojoTest.java:124)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
        at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:168)
        at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
        at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException

Maven version that I am using is maven 3.3.9.

Comment: Please provide the dependecies your using (from the effective POM).

Comment: what after `Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:` ?

Comment: @Puce, question updated.

Comment: @Faisal same error repeats again

Comment: I am not sure about the visibility of your question on SO. maybe you can checkout the maven-compat mailing list: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-compat/mail-lists.html

Comment: Are you writing a maven-plugin ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am writing unit test for maven customized mojos.

Comment: The usage of maven-compat is only usefull if you need to be compatible with Maven 2 ...if not your should not use it...Furthermore the question is what kind of plugin and how your tests look like there might be better ideas...